# Find all SELECT statements without a WHERE clause using a regex

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I'm trying to scan my codebase to find all *select* queries without a *where* clause using regex. The results will be fed into an IDE or a grep file output, but must contain the full matching queries only.

My biggest challenge is getting the entire statement without the WHERE. The caveats are:

- some selects don't have a where but also don't have a FROM
- some selects target a database view (always starts with a **vw**) which don't need a where clause

Here's a sample list of all queries fetched from one file:

```
'
      DECLARE @RowsAffected INT = 0;

      INSERT INTO tblInvoice (InvID, OcID, InvTimeStamp)
      SELECT DISTINCT OcInvID, OcID, GETDATE() AS InvTimeStamp
      FROM tblOrderCost OC WITH(NOLOCK)
      INNER JOIN tblVendor WITH(NOLOCK) ON InvVendorID = VendorID AND VendorType = 1 -- 1 for supplier.
      INNER JOIN #tmpOpID tmp WITH(NOLOCK) ON tmp.OpID = OcOpID
        WHERE     id   =     ' . quote($order_id, NUMERIC);
        
        
            $sql = ' SELECT     rphrpid,rphwho,rphdate,rphnotes,opid
             FROM       tblReplacementPartHistory (nolock)
             INNER JOIN tblReplacementPart (nolock)
             ON         rphrpid = rpid
             INNER JOIN tblOrderProduct (nolock)
             ON         rpopid = opid
             WHERE      oporid =' . quote($order_id, NUMERIC)
          . 'ORDER BY   rphrpid';

                 
                 
select * from table where id = 1;


'
select count()
';

      DECLARE @RowsAffected INT = 0;

      INSERT INTO tblInvoice (InvID, OcID, InvTimeStamp)
      SELECT DISTINCT OcInvID, OcID, GETDATE() AS InvTimeStamp
      FROM tblOrderCost OC WITH(NOLOCK)
      INNER JOIN tblVendor WITH(NOLOCK) ON InvVendorID = VendorID AND VendorType = 1
      INNER JOIN #tmpOpID tmp WITH(NOLOCK) ON tmp.OpID = OcOpID';
        
        
            $sql = ' SELECT     rphrpid,rphwho,rphdate,rphnotes,opid
             FROM       tblReplacementPartHistory (nolock)
             INNER JOIN tblReplacementPart (nolock)
             ON         rphrpid = rpid
             INNER JOIN tblOrderProduct (nolock)
             ON         rpopid = opid
             ORDER BY   rphrpid';



                SELECT     rphrpid,rphwho,rphdate,rphnotes,opid
             FROM       vwOrder';
                 
                 
select * from tbl;
```

I tried several variations of regex patterns and the closest I got was finding matches with the WHERE line stripped out. I would like to have the entire match made *only* if the query does not have a WHERE clause. I tried the following

```
SELECT(.*)(\s)*FROM(\s|.)+?((?!.*where))(?=(';|";|;))
SELECT\s*(?!.*\s*where|vw(\w)*).*\s*(';|";|;)
SELECT[^;\n]*(?:\n(?![^\n;]*where)[^;\n]*)*\n[\n]*
```

The work can also be tested in the regex101 sandbox: https://regex101.com/r/jvbLOE/1

What I expect to see, given the sample data, is only three matches

```
1. SELECT DISTINCT OcInvID, OcID, GETDATE() AS InvTimeStamp
      FROM tblOrderCost OC WITH(NOLOCK)
      INNER JOIN tblVendor WITH(NOLOCK) ON InvVendorID = VendorID AND VendorType = 1 
      INNER JOIN #tmpOpID tmp WITH(NOLOCK) ON tmp.OpID = OcOpID';

2. SELECT     rphrpid,rphwho,rphdate,rphnotes,opid
             FROM       tblReplacementPartHistory (nolock)
             INNER JOIN tblReplacementPart (nolock)
             ON         rphrpid = rpid
             INNER JOIN tblOrderProduct (nolock)
             ON         rpopid = opid
             ORDER BY   rphrpid';

3. select * from tbl;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: It's a MSSQL but I'm not sure how it relates to the regex rule as we're simply looking at text

Comment: This kind of thing will be very difficult for a regexp. You can check if the word `WHERE` doesn't appear, but it's hard to make it stop at the end of a single query. And it will also have a problem if the word `WHERE` appears in a string literal. RegExp is not really the right tool for this.

Comment: @Barmar what do you recommend instead?

Comment: There are several SQL parser libraries for Python. Google it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following regex to match select queries not having a where clause in it based on your example.

```
/(?!.*where)select.*?;/gis
```

Regex 101 example:

https://regex101.com/r/XaGXp6/1

Comment: Worked like a charm. Accepted answer!

Comment: How can I include a FROM in there? I need to omit all selects that don't query a table

Comment: That's a different question. I may have a look into that.